# integer empty variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, reduce

I don't know why this return undefined?

```
var array = [6, 4, 6, 9];
var min;
var findminimum =   function(){
        array.reduce(function(prev, cur, index, array) {
                    if (cur < min) {
                        min = cur;
                    }
        }, 0);
        return min;
    };
console.log(findminimum());
```

but when i set:

```
var min = 20;
```

it is run ok, so anyone can explain me how to properly define num variable?

Comment: if `cur < min` is never met, you never assign the `min` variable a value, meaning when it `return min`'s, it returns `null`. Just initialize min to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: If `min` isn't set, `cur < min` will be comparing a number to undefined which is false, `min` will never be set. One solution would be to additionally check if `min` is unset. Eg. `if(cur < min || min === undefined)`

Comment: you are right, thank you :)

Comment: Whats the point of reducing the array here if you are not comparing `prev` with `cur` and not providing `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` for the initial value argument.

Answer (score 1):

In fact `undefined` in Javascript means that, this variable is not yet defined and that's exactly what's happening in your case:

You are using the variable `min` before assigning a value to it, so :

```
if (cur < min)
```

Will always return `false`, so there's no value assigned to `min` and `min = cur;` will never be reached, and your function will return `undefined`.

**EDIT:**

If you only write `var min;` you are just declaring the variable `min` in order to use it, you have to initialize it by assigning a value to it, in your case you should write:

```
var min = 0;
```

Now `min` will have the value `0`, you can then compare it with other variables.

Comment: The underlying problem is that he uses free variables inside `findminimum`

Comment: Yes kind of, and `min` variable should be declared inside `findminimum` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to min otherwise you won't be able to test its value

```
if (typeof min == "undefined" || cur < min) {
    min = cur;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because `min` is not initialized to a value it is `undefined`. Therefore your comparison `if (cur < min)` is never true and `min` continues to be undefined. Also, if you're going to use `reduce()` for this instead of a simple loop, you may want to utilize it differently, here's a code sample that works:

```
var array = [6, 4, 6, 9, 1, -99];
var min = 9999;
var findminimum = function () {
    // you could return the final output of reduce()...
    return array.reduce(function (prev, cur, index, array) {
        if (cur < min) {
            min = cur;
        }

        return min; // ...then this return statement would be here inside the reduce callback
    }, 0);
};
console.log(findminimum());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is, you use a variable from ouside of reduce `min` to store the minimum of the array. [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a method for getting a single result out of the iteration with a possible given start value.

Problems (order in reverse):

- `reduce(..., 0)` start with 0. makes no sense, because it could be a minimum  or a value which is too small, like in your array `[6, 4, 6, 9]`.
- better take no `initialValue`, because if no `initialValue` is given than reduce takes the first two elements for `prev` and `cur`. If the array has only one element, then this element is returned.
- The short form of the required reduce:

  ```
  min = array.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
      return cur < prev ? cur : prev;
  });
  ```

Now you can put it into a function for the minimum and take an array as parameter:

```js
function getMinimum(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        return cur < prev ? cur : prev;
    });
}

document.write(getMinimum([6, 4, 6, 9]) + '<br>');
document.write(getMinimum([6, 4]) + '<br>');
document.write(getMinimum([42]) + '<br>');
```